# Mysql query script weird

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, crud

first im sorry my english is not too good,

i just wondering about something i dont know and its weird for me
so, example : i have 2 tables in my mysql database
let say 1st table called "one" second one is "two"
if i want to CRUD from table "one" using PHP script, i dont need to use backtick --> ` <-- mark, i dont know how to call it in english, i just using, eg:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM one WHERE id='1'");
```

but i dont know why, if i want to do the same for table "Two" i must use --> ` <-- mark, and it doesnt work if i not using that, its working if i use this :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `two` WHERE `id`='1'");
```

maybe some one know about this, so i will not think if its weird anymore :D

thank you, i hope you guys understand my language

regards
Yongki Agustinus

Comment: it's called `backtick`, by the way.

Comment: Your tables are presumably not called `one` and `two`, and the real name of `two` is in [this list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom the actual table name i use are msgmember and news

Comment: define `'doesnt work'`. do you get any error from `mysql_error()`? if not - there is probable just no data in the table two

Comment: no, im not get any error message, but the data is not inserted,
in my table i have a column named "date" and "date" is listed as reserved word, is that the problem ?

Comment: i just checking, i think the problem is if i use more than 1 reserved word as column name and table name as well, because i have other table with one column using reserved word as name and its working as normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `two` table most likely named after some of [mysql reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) (or the name contains some non-alphanumeric symbol) and thus require additional formatting

Comment: hi @Your Common Sense the actual table name i use are msgmember and news